# Queryset filter to filter response that exactly contains the value as substring in django views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset, django-filter

I have created filters that filter API responses, if the response contains at least one letter in the value as substring, I need to create a filter to filter responses that **exactly contain** the value as a substring in Django views.

```
**Existing code in views.py**
class UserSearchFilterAPIView(APIView):
def get(self,request,*args,**kargs):
    queryset=Joineduserdatanew.objects.all()
    
    #Custom filter
    
    surname=self.request.query_params.get('surname',None)
    firstname=self.request.query_params.get('firstname',None)
    login=self.request.query_params.get('login',None)
    racfid=self.request.query_params.get('racfid',None)
    assignee=self.request.query_params.get('assignee',None)
    phonenumber=self.request.query_params.get('phonenumber',None)
    company_or_group=self.request.query_params.get('company_or_group',None)
    email=self.request.query_params.get('email',None)
    segment=self.request.query_params.get('segment',None)
    if surname:
        queryset=queryset.filter(surname__icontains=surname)
    if firstname:
        queryset=queryset.filter(firstname__icontains=firstname)
    if login:
        queryset=queryset.filter(login__icontains=login)
    if racfid:
        queryset=queryset.filter(racfid__icontains=racfid)
    if assignee:
        queryset=queryset.filter(assignee__icontains=assignee)
    if phonenumber:
        queryset=queryset.filter(phonenumber__icontains=phonenumber)
    if company_or_group:
        queryset=queryset.filter(company_or_group__icontains=company_or_group)
    if email:
        queryset=queryset.filter(email__icontains=email)
    if segment:
        queryset=queryset.filter(segment__icontains=segment)
        
    serializer=JoineduserdatanewSerialization(queryset,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Example:
if company_or_group is given as : "aaa" ,it returns results containing at least one 'a' but I need to filter that the company_or_group in the API response **exactly containing "aaa"** as a substring in that company_or_group field.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you filter for `queryset.filter(company_or_group__icontains='aaa'), you only get back results where the string `company_or_group` has three consecutive a's. You say that it returns results containing at least one a. I cannot reproduce this behavior. Are you sure that the variable `company_or_group` is set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use without `icontains` for that:

```
queryset=queryset.filter(company_or_group=company_or_group)
```

Or [`iexact`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#iexact) to case insensitivity:

```
queryset=queryset.filter(company_or_group__iexact=company_or_group)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. This will filter on an exact match for the entire value, but the problem is that it should __contain__ the exact match.